# Python yFInance api how to get close share price instead of adjusted close share price?

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I am trying to get closing share price from yFinance API for Devon `DVN`. The problem is that the API gives `adjusted closing share price` as `closing share price` in the response data which can sometimes be different.

As seen in yahoo finance, DVN closing share price for 9th Sept 2021 was 28.45, and adjusted closing share price was 27.96

[image]

In API response from yFinance I get the closing share price as 27.96 which should be the adjusted value, not the closing value.

[image]

Now how do I get the closing share price from yFinance instead of adjusted share price?

Comment: In the Yahoo Finance download, you can get both the closing price and the adjusted closing price. `data = yf.download("DVN", start='2021-09-01', end='2021-09-11')`

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Do post your answer below so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the download function of Yahoo Finance, you can get both the closing price and the adjusted closing price.

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("DVN", start='2021-09-01', end='2021-09-11')

data
    Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2021-08-31  29.660000   30.320000   29.420000   29.549999   29.041054   11534800
2021-09-01  29.400000   29.590000   27.670000   28.240000   27.753616   20559000
2021-09-02  28.600000   29.969999   28.600000   29.320000   28.815016   11711300
2021-09-03  29.209999   29.799999   29.000000   29.170000   28.667601   7305300
2021-09-07  28.900000   29.330000   28.730000   29.059999   28.559494   5939700
2021-09-08  29.250000   29.620001   28.030001   28.230000   27.743790   8874000
2021-09-09  28.010000   29.080000   27.730000   28.450001   27.960001   9205700
2021-09-10  28.700001   29.030001   28.020000   28.070000   28.070000   6581800
```